# Calculating the no. of days for the selected date period using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a calculated column on a SSAS cube to work out the following:

```
Net Net X Rate = [Net Net Revenue] / [X] 

where X = no of days
```

I need an output for X (using MDX), Something like the no. of days for the date period selected

For example upon the selection of

30 days for the chosen month of April 2021
X = 30
rate for 30 days

14 days for the chosen month of December 2020
X=14
rate for 14 days

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to SSAS at this point, but maybe somthing like

```
Net Net X Rate = [Net Net Revenue] / COUNT( EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Day].Members )
```

Answered here maybe: [Count children members in MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677641/count-children-members-in-mdx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help: DateDiffDays or .

I had something like this in mind: DateDiffDays([Measures].[From_Date], Now()). It will count the days difference between some day in the past and now. DateDiffWorkdays will get you a number of working days between two dates.

Alternatively, you could pre-calculate this value in a view and then pull the number into a cube.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Date dimension is on day granularity, a very efficient way from query performance point of view to get what you want would be to add a column to your date dimension table. This could either be done in a view in the relational data model, or in the DVS as a calculated column. Name it e. g. `number of days` or just `X`, and make it be the value 1 on each row, i. e. the column expression is just `1`. Then you create a new measure group based on this table, with the only measure being `X`, which would just sum this column. Then, whatever your query context would be, the `X` measure would just be the number of days. If you want, you can then make the measure invisible.